# Sync local files with remote

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use node.js, and I want to sync my local dirrectory with remote one.

For example: I have a remote folder with files something like this: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v13.5.0/

I also have a folder on my local computer, for instance, it is located in "C:/files", when I start the script, It should watch the remote server, and update my local files when any file on the server is changed.

I have been looking for a node module for thee days, and I still haven't found a good one for this. My remote server is also not protected with password (I want everyone can visit this link also).

Comment: please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did I ask a bad question? I tried to explain my problem good

Comment: You need to post what you've tried, what issues you're having, preferably with minimal reproducible example code that shows the issues you're having.  It's difficult for people to help you without know what the issues are.  If you're just looking for a node module, this isn't the place for that.